# Setup Multiple Environments in Parallel Azure DevOps

Tags: azure, automation, azure-devops

I have a query to setup multiple environments at a time so that we can discreetly test multiple projects at once. **Ideally we should be able to spin these environments up and down as necessary**.

We have microservice based architecture and are mostly using azure PAAS services in our infrastructure.

Currently i have tried to automate our infrastructure through terraform its almost done but next step is deployment of code as services are not containerized so tried using azure pipelines but its a huge task, can i get any better idea for this that how we could do this.

Comment: I think that your question is too general. Please try first achieve what you want and then share with us where you see a problem. If you have complex microservice architecture it can take some time to create full pipeline however you have a tools to avoid duplication like templates and many others. All depends to specific requirements. If you want to deploy your code into Web App in the simplest manner this is a one task once you have a package ready. So really all depends on requirements. Start with small but working example and then progress towards implementing further requirements.

Comment: Please provide feedback if the suggested answer was helpful or not.

Answer (score 0):

Should look at leveraging [Azure Pipeline Templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops) Once this is defined then can reuse it everywhere.  For instance with terraform created a template for doing the plan and apply that just needs to be fed in the directory the terraform is located in.  This saved time across all projects as we just need to reference our template and the rest was taken care of.

In terms of your other question with the ability to spin up and spin down this can be easily done if the application is architected with that in mind.  Keep in mind for deployment certain things where names must be unique: storage account, app service and things that are potentially shared: i.e. network.

The other piece to consider is how to ensure these ad hoc environments are actually being spun down.  Would recommend something like a tagging strategy or process that cleans up resources that haven't been deployed in x amount of days.